# BigQuery Difference Between 2 Tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to find and return rows that DON'T match, while searching between 2 tables

Both tables have the same 3 columns. Both tables have the exact same amount of IDs. The tables are "a" and "b"

Cols; (Id, country, passfail)

I'm trying to return all the rows where passfail does not match between the tables (where id's match)

I've tried to run 2 queries but cant seem to print the resulting rows.

---

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b ON (a.passfail = b.passfail)
WHERE a.passfail IS NULL
```

---

---

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM a 
AS a JOIN b 
AS b 
ON a.passfail = b.passfail 
WHERE a.passfail != b.passfail
```

---

Neither of those queries seems to work for me.

Any help or recommendations are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You must join on the **id** field. Here is an example:

```
WITH a as (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, country STRING, passfail BOOL>>[(1, 'uk', true), (3, 'fr', false)])),
     b as (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, country STRING, passfail BOOL>>[(1, 'uk', true), (3, 'fr', true)]))

SELECT
  a.*
FROM
  a
LEFT JOIN
  b
ON
  (a.id = b.id)
WHERE
  a.passfail != b.passfail
```

Comment: This is good.  Consider using a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and selecting from both `a` and `b` to see mismatches in both tables.

Comment: The proposed query retrieves all the matches by ids that exist on both tables ad the filter `a.passfail != b.passfail` select the ones that doesn't match on passfail . @Seamus, if the query answers your question, please consider accepting it. But if not, feel free to ask any clarifications.